# Simple If Then statement not working the way I think it should

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm relatively new to VB and I'm being forced to use the in-line coding method. I would like to check for a not null value for a variable and then display an image. That's all I want it to do. Here's a couple of instances of what I've tried to do.

```
<% if ACTL is not nothing then %>
<img id="ACTLLogo" src="<%= ACTL %>" />
<% else end if %>
```

or this:

```
<% if ACTL is nothing then %>
&nbsp;
<% else %>
<img id="ACTLLogo" src="<%= ACTL %>
<% end if %>
```

or this:

```
<% if String.IsNullOrEmpty(ACTL) then %>
&nbsp;
<% else %>
<img id="ACTLLogo" src="<%= ACTL %>
<% end if %>
```

When I do just the  part without the if statements, the logo shows up fine, so I'm thinking I just don't know how to do in-line coding IF statements in ASP Classic. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or ASP Classic?

Comment: OK, remove the VB.NETtag then

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a variable is NULL, use the `IsNull` function:

```
If Not IsNull(ACTL) Then
    Response.Write "<img src='" & ACTL & "' id='ACTLLogo'>"
End If
```

You can also check whether the variable is EMPTY (which is what you get if, for example, you do a `Request.Form("fld")` and the form does not have a field called `fld`) using the, you guessed it, `IsEmpty` function:

```
If IsEmpty(Request.Form("fld")) Then
    Response.Write "<p class='msg'>No such field!</p>"
End If
```

If all you care about is whether the variable has a value, any value, then you can do a quick-and-dirty string conversion:

```
If ACTL & "" <> "" Then
    ...
End If
```

This latter trick is very useful for avoiding the type mismatch errors you can get if a variable is unexpectedly NULL, without having to add `If Not IsNull(...)` all over the place.

Comment: Nice!  Like to see the quick and the dirty! +1

Answer (score -1):

In ASP Classic you can use `<% if ACTL <>"" %>`

You could also write your code like this, which removes the need to close the asp tag.

```
<% 
if ACTL <>"" then
response.write("<img id=""ACTLLogo"" src="""&ACTL&""" />")
end if
%>
```

Might be a bit easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Yeah, this totally worked. Thanks. I will mark it as the answer soon as I can.

Comment: Thank you appreciate it.

Comment: I have added some improved code as an alternative to opening and closing the <% %>

Comment: @Joseph: Be careful with this as it will not detect null or nothing. Pulling data from a database, for instance, may return null values. To remedy this try using a quick and dirty piece of code, like so: `If ACTL & "" <> "" Then`.

Comment: @Lima: You've missed various closings, such as the speech marks and the bracket from your `Response.Write` line. Using single speech marks for attributes in your (Response.Write) mark-up